# Math.pow() coming out wrong

Tags: javascript, excel, math, jquery-calculation

I'm trying to create a JavaScript version of this equation that I got working in Excel:

Excel version:

```
10000*(1+0.06)^30+6000*(((1+0.06)^30-1)/0.06)
```

This calculates out to `531784.029`

JavaScript version:

```
console.log(10000*(1+0.06)^30+6000*(((1+0.06)^30-1)/0.06));
```

Returns: `2789622`

Or if I try to use `Math.pow()`:

```
console.log(10000*(Math.pow(1+.06),30)+6000*(Math.pow((1+.06),30-1)/.06));
```

Returns: `841838.7898974773`

I'm completely stumped after about 6 hours. How do I recreate that excel calculation and get the same number?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not shortcutting the 30-1 and 1+0.06?

Comment: `(1+0.06)^30` are you sure that's correct? the `^` does an XOR in JavaScript, not power, like in Excel

Comment: Also, in your second try `(Math.pow(1+.06),30)` the brackets are wrong. What that would do is _evaluate_ `Math.pow(1+.06)` then discard it and return `30` due to the comma - you probably want `Math.pow(1+.06,30)`

Comment: I'm using (1+.06) because once I've got this worked out that ".06" will actually be variable coming from an input. It's an interest rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same behavior as in excel you just have the wrong order of operators and wrong parameters to the `Math.pow`function in js, it should be like this:

```js
console.log(10000*(Math.pow(1+.06,30))+6000*((Math.pow(1+.06,30)-1)/0.06));
```

the `^` operator in javascript is not the same as in excel, in js it means a bitwise xor operation, while in excel it means the same as the `Math.pow`.

The `Math.pow`function in javascript takes two parameters, so for example to make the same operation as in excel `1.06^30` you would do `Math.pow(1.06,30)`in javascript.

by the way maybe is just something you put for the example but you dont need to add `1+.06`you could just write `1.06`:

```js
 console.log(10000*(Math.pow(1.06,30))+6000*((Math.pow(1.06,30)-1)/0.06));
```

Comment: I was just about to hit Post saying more or less the same but you were just around 2 seconds faster than me :)

Comment: @vlaz Thanks for the js snippet code... I was wondering how to do that

Comment: It's quite embarassing, really but it took me, like _a month_ to realise there is a button in the editor when you're posting. It's the little page with `<>` in it icon which is pretty much in the middle of the buttons.

Comment: Also, in case anyone else ever needs this, it's an equation for compound interest over 30 years at 6% interest with $6000 being added at the END of each year.